# Poisson manifolds that do not come from quotient of symplectic manifold by Lie groups?

Tags: group-actions, symplectic-geometry, poisson-geometry

Given a lie group $G$ that acts over a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ then its quotient $M/G$ (under mild hipothesis) is a Poisson manifold.

This is an very useful way to construct Poisson manifolds from symplectic manifolds alreadly known.

I am asking myself if there is an example of a Poisson manifold that do not arises as a quotient of symplectic manifold. Maybe a fully degenerated Poisson bracket can gives us some nice examples?